# Dynamic Form In Ionic and Get value of ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create a Dynamic Form where I want to make Form from JSON data. I am able to create a form but i want to access that dynamic created form and get value of model (input field)on submit button.
  I have Created a Fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/anujsphinx/dpzgeyt8/2/) for that .Want to get ng-model value of every field.
 I am doing wrong in HTML

```
 <ion-view view-title="Search" ng-app="myAp">
  <ion-content ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <h1>Submit</h1>
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="loginuser.use" name="text" placeholder="Your Username" required>
    <span class="input-label">Email Id</span>
                    <input type="email" ng-model="loginuser.email" name="email" placeholder="Your Username" required>
    <div data-ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
     <span class="input-label">{{item.name}} </span>
                    <input type="{{item.type}}" ng-model="newVar" name="email" placeholder="{{item.placeholder}}" required> {{newVar}}
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="checkResult()">
        Submit
    </button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: here is javascript solution if you find useful https://jsfiddle.net/hv2f1gLe/ . I have done for only two filelds. you may find dynamic way to get data from that form.

Comment: Thanks but main problem is that name will create dynamic .

Comment: yes you can google it to get all fields from a form using loop.

Comment: Y downvote my qn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way you can get values of all form elements.
add new form element and add input fields within form.

```
<form name="newForm">
...   //input elements
</form>
```

add a loop to get values of all elements from a form

```
$scope.checkResult = function(){
    var newForm = document.newForm;
    for(i=0;i<newForm.elements.length;i++){
        console.log(newForm.elements[i].value);
    }  
  }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks NImesh. You did my half work .I updated now https://jsfiddle.net/anujsphinx/hv2f1gLe/6/